# Crashlytics: Is it possible to get crash info programmatically like exception code or any message

Tags: ios, google-fabric

I need to get some info about crash happened inside the app like some exception code and message. Is it possible via `Crashlytics` or some additional tools?

I found that I can set the delegate to get instance of `CLSReport`, but can't find such info as `exception code` and `message` in this class' interface.

Also tried `PLCrashReporting`, but seems like it doesn't work when another crash reporting Framework like `Firebase` or `Crashlytics` is installed.

Does anyone know where to look for such info? Or if it's impossible now, is this feature going to be implemented in near future?

Answer (score 2):

Mike from Fabric here. Currently getting the crash report programmatically isn't supported and isn't on our immediate roadmap to add in.